# resultado exibido ultrapassando a condição

Tags: javascript

tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```js
var num = 0;
while (num <= 12) {
  console.log(num);
  num = num + 2;
}
```

verificando aqui agora na hora de postar a dúvida, vi que o resultado conta até 12, porém testando no console do meu browser o resultado é exibido até 14.

fiquei sem entender.

P.S: estou aprendendo!

Comment: Essa pergunta é duplicata, só não achei a outra pergunta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `14` que é exibido não é produto do seu `console.log`, e sim o resultado do último *statement* do `while`.

Veja o que acontece ao adicionar os resultados em um array:

```js
var num = 0;
var numbers = [];
while (num <= 12) {
  numbers.push(num);
  num = num + 2;
}

console.log(numbers);
```

Ele faz a iteração corretamente, exibindo até o `12`.

O que acontece é que o console do seu browser exibe o resultado do último *statement* na saída padrão. O snippet do StackOverflow só exibe o que de fato foi para a saída padrão pelo `console.log`.

Faça o seguinte teste:

```js
var num = 0;
while (num <= 12) {
  console.log(num);
  num = num + 2;

  console.log("Próximo...");
}
```

Veja que no seu console, o `14` parou de aparecer, mas agora você vê `undefined` após o `12`. Esse é o resultado do `console.log("Próximo...")`.

> Perceba que o valor de `num` depois de tudo é `14`, mas ele não é capturado pelo `console.log` por sair do `while`!

Comment: agora sim entendi =)